# Python miscounts len() for multiline string

Tags: python, cgi

Given a simple program for testing CGI with Apache server

```
#!C:/Python311/python.exe

html = """<!doctype html />
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello CGI World</h1>
</body>
</html>"""
print( "Content-Type: text/html" ) 
print( f"Content-Length: {len(html)}" )
print( "" )                         
print( html )
```

The problem in `len(html)` result less than actual. In editor (fig.1) we see 98 selected symbols.
[image]

But in browser we see 91 symbol
[image]

And response body cropped by it length
[image]

I tried to display string symbol-by-symbol in Python console and found out that '\n' symbols comes alone while in editor and browser they are '\r\n' (my suggestion). In any case single-line string has no problem.

I tried to replace '\n' for '\r\n' (`.replace('\n','\r\n')`) but the problem not solves, browser shows extra 'CR' symbools and body still cropped.

Thanks forward for any ideas

Comment: @mozway: What? `html` doesn't even have any leading or trailing whitespace to strip.

Comment: @mozway thanks, but stilll 91 symbols and cropping ((

Comment: If I replace `\n` with `\r\n` in my VS Code I get 98.

Comment: @user56700 Is it VS editor settings or replacing by hand?

Comment: It doesn't matter, It also works directly in Python interpreter.

Comment: @mozway wrong user, but I forgive you too :)

Comment: @user2357112 I'm gonna go get a coffee ;)

Comment: writing `\r\n` by hand is not exactly what I want

Comment: @DNS But multistring in Python will always use \n as new line.

Comment: Maybe smth like raw string / decoding / buffer length ?

Comment: @DNS Well, you wrote the html variable by hand, the output from a browser in some form might give a different result.

Comment: Browser gets 98 symbols, all OK. I looking a way to get content length in Python code

Comment: Then that is a new question, try to setup an example using Selenium or Beautiful Soup to get the html data and count that data and see if it works that way.

Comment: I think the web server is supposed to handle the Content-Length header for you - I don't think you actually need to provide it yourself. Have you tried just not printing a Content-Length header?

Comment: @user2357112 Right, I don't. But question is how to do it

Answer (score 1):

If I replace `\n` with `\r\n` I get exactly 98.

```
html = """<!doctype html />
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello CGI World</h1>
</body>
</html>"""
print("Content-Type: text/html")
html_length = len(html.replace('\n', '\r\n'))
print(f"Content-Length: {html_length}")
print("")
```

Result:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 98
```

In Python interpreter:

```
Python 3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> html = """<!doctype html />
... <html>
... <head>
... </head>
... <body>
...     <h1>Hello CGI World</h1>
... </body>
... </html>"""
>>> print("Content-Type: text/html")
Content-Type: text/html
>>> html_length = len(html.replace('\n', '\r\n'))
>>> print(f"Content-Length: {html_length}")
Content-Length: 98
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But in this way we make a copy of `html` just for length computing. Seems to be more efficient algo

Comment: I also get OK in such way `extra = html.count('\n')` `print( f"Content-Length: {len(html) + extra}" )` But I don't like this solution. Python is a great lang, it should have pretty solution)

Answer (score 1):

The Content-Length header is supposed to give the size of the message body in bytes. That is not the same as the length of the `html` string, because you're on Windows, and the `\n` characters get translated to Windows `\r\n` line breaks when you print them. Each line break becomes two characters.

Additionally, any characters that get encoded to more than 1 byte in the encoding specified by `sys.stdout.encoding` will also cause a length mismatch (and if `sys.stdout.encoding` is something weird, you might not be able to print some characters, or the browser might not understand what it's looking at).

You don't need to provide a Content-Length header in a CGI script - the web server will handle it for you. If you really want to compute Content-Length yourself, though, you can perform newline translation and encoding and check the length of the resulting bytestring:

```
import sys

temp = html
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    temp = temp.replace('\n', '\r\n')
temp = temp.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
content_length = len(temp)
```

You can also explicitly set `sys.stdout.encoding` with `sys.stdout.reconfigure`, or change line break translation behavior:

```
# Sets sys.stdout.encoding to 'utf-8'
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

# Disables \n -> \r\n translation
sys.stdout.reconfigure(newline='\n')
```

or write arbitrary bytes directly to `sys.stdout.buffer` if you want more control.

Comment: Thanks! But I suppose that there is algo without `replace` making a copy of string. In my example html a little string but real html is much more longer. In such case it is really better to exclude Content-Length header. But in other case(s) the problem may arise again...